# Hide bottom of div containing iframe via CSS

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I have any iframe in my html page! I had set iframe height to 100% and scrolling=no.
But the framed page is having lots of white space at bottom!
I need to remove 100px of bottom via stylesheet but i cannot change iframe height!

I can place iframe in a div and then hide bottom part of div via css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place the iframe in a div with height 100% for iframe and adjust the height of the div according to it by giving fixed height (iframe height -100px). The you need to remove scroll of that div using the below css styles:

```
overflow-y:hidden;
overflow-x:hidden;
```